# how to get index, out of bash array in dictionary

Tags: arrays, bash, dictionary

I have this code -->

```
list=("kek" "lol")
dict+=(["memes"]=$list)
```

with array, and the dictionary ( i guess ).
now i want to get, for example, second index out of the list, but using dictionary.
Something like
`echo ${dict[1]}`, but that does not print out anything, even tho if to call `echo ${dict[0]}`, it will print out `kek`. So my guess that i have done something wrong on declaring dictionary step... and i was not able to google anything about this issue for some reason.
So... How do i do it?

Comment: If `dict` was empty, there is only one index in `dict`. Do you understand that `$list` is the same as `${list[0]}`, it's only the first element of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of an associative array is always a scalar. It can't be an indexed array. You could store instead the **name** of the array (`list`) into the dictionary and use a *nameref* to access the array:

```
list=(kek lol)
dict+=([memes]=list) # Store name of array
declare -n plist=${dict[memes]} # Fetch the list
echo ${plist[0]} # Outputs kek
```

Comment: Yeah, that will work

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, you can do it with just declaring the dictionary this way `dict+=(["memes"]="kek" "lol")` , and it will work, still interesting, if it even possible to declare it via variable.
Thought i was not able to find a way to get the list out of dictionary using the key (with key-"memes" get the list-value with "kek" and "lol").

So, if someone will be interested how i achived getting the list out of dictionary by the key:

```
declare -A dict
dict+=( ["memes"]="kek,lol" )
dict+=( ["memes2"]="kek2,lol2" )
for key in ${!dict[@]}
do
    echo "key is: $key"
    IFS=',' read -r -a list_dict <<< "${dict[$key]}"
    for values_by_the_key in ${list_dict[@]}
    do
        echo "value: $values_by_the_key"
    done
done
```

So, basically it value of the key is not a list, just a string, that is converted then into the list... but it works!:)

Comment: I'm surprised that this works, but if it does, shouldn't it also be possible to write it as `dict+=([memes]="${list[@]}")`?

Comment: This `dict+=(["memes"]="kek" "lol")` works as i wanted it to work (im able to get values by index for example `echo ${dict[0]}` will print `kek` and `echo ${dict[1]}` will print `lol`, the `dict+=([memes]="${list[@]}")` works interestingly, but not the way i wanted ( echo `echo ${dict[0]}` gives me `kek lol`, and `echo ${dict[1]}` gives `lol`